# Does the meter spin backwards with an inductive load during the negative half?

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose I connect an inductor directly to the mains. Since inductor cannot dissipate any power, does the meter run backwards ? My textbook simply says that the inductor gives back the current to the mains during the negative half. But, isn't it like supplying power to the grid ?

Comment: An ideal inductor will take energy from the grid during part of the 60 Hz cycle and return the same amount of energy back during another part of the cycle. That's true. Now whether a standard electrical meter will accurately record the fact that the net power consumed by the inductor is zero is an engineering question. It should read zero, but on the other hand if the meter simply monitors the average current flow without properly taking into account the phase between the voltage and current, then it might incorrectly assume that the inductor is consuming power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, isn't it like supplying power to the grid ?

More like 'giving it back'; the energy must flow to the inductor first, during a half-cycle, and then the energy stored by the inductor flows back to the grid during the remaining half-cycle.

> does the meter run backwards ?

That depends on the particulars of the meter but, given the AC mains frequency, an electro-mechanical meter would I think, at most, vibrate a bit back and forth.

I remember measuring the transfer function of an electro-mechanical ammeter in my first EE lab and we found that, for frequencies above a few Hz, the meter pointer essentially stood still.